# Generating id selector dynamically based on user-input

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I am facing a problem in jQuery selector. I am generating selector string dynamically based on user-input as show below :-

```
jQuery("#" + userInput + "-edit").modal("show")
```

When the user enters value like `"AdvancedResults."` Selector becomes

```
jQuery("#AdvancedResults.-edit").modal("show")
```

which does not return expected element, despite the fact that

Am I doing something patchy ? Is there any better way to solve this problem ?

Btw, apologising for newbie question, as I am new to JS world.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share the html mark up? or demo?

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

Use the escaping rules from the [jQuery selectors API](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) as follows:

```
$("#AdvancedResults\\.-edit").modal("show");
```

You can replace . to \. dynamically using str.replace():

```js
var str = "AdvancedResults.";
str = str.replace(/\./g, "\\."); // it will add add \\ dynamically before .
console.log($("#"+str+'-edit').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="AdvancedResults.-edit"  type="text"/>
```

Comment: User can enter any special character.  Solution provided by you, will work only for .(dot).

Answer (score 1):

If your element does have an id `#AdvancedResults.-edit`, that is, includes a dot, you must escape it with `\\` as stated in the docs [jQuery Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`[attribute=""]`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)** selector in such cases where the parameter is dynamic and might contain special chars not supports by jQuery `#` - ID selector.

```
jQuery("[id='" + userInput + "-edit']").modal("show")
```

Example snippet :

```js
var userInput = "abc.";
alert(jQuery("[id='" + userInput + "-edit']").val())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="abc.-edit" value="test"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it using attribute hack.

It's as follow :-

```
jQuery("[id='" + userInput + "-edit']").modal("show");
```

It worked perfectly for me.